# typeerror Cannot read property 'split' of undefined

Tags: javascript

I keep getting this error over this very basic code.

```
// utils/validateEmails.js
const re = /^(([^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;

export default (emails) => {
    const invalidEmails = emails.split(',')
        .map(email => email.trim())
        .filter(email => re.test(email) === false);

    if(invalidEmails.length) {
        return `These emails are invalid: ${invalidEmails}`;
    }

    return;
};
```

Used like

```
import validateEmails from '../../utils/validateEmails'

// snip    

errors.emails = validateEmails(values.emails)
```

Comment: What is the value of `emails`?

Comment: @AnkitAgarwal I can't even test it. Create-react-app keeps throwing the error in my face that I can't even try it.

Comment: emails is undefined indeed as you never instantiate this variable.

Comment: import validateEmails from '../../utils/validateEmails';
errors.emails = validateEmails(values.emails);

I did call it in a different page and it should've worked fine I think.

Comment: its because the variable you are splitting isnt defined and doesnt have any value

Comment: Whatever value you're passing to this function (ie `values.emails`) is undefined. There doesn't seem to be anything wrong with the code in your question (except that it can return `undefined` which doesn't seem like a good idea)

Answer (score 0):

you would have to assign a value to the  variable `emails`..

```
emails = 'e@a.com,c@r.com,e@e.com';
```

split is a property of the object `string`.. object properties are not available if an object is undefined.

Comment: OP **has** defined the variable `emails`; it is the single argument to the exported function.

Comment: yes but he did not assign a value to it..

' if the variable that is being evaluated does not have an assigned value'

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/undefined

Comment: OP says they're calling it via `validateEmails(values.emails)` but they neglect to mention where `values` comes from or if `values.emails` is defined (presumably not). Their issue is definitely **not** that the `emails` variable is not defined though

Comment: 'heir issue is definitely not that the emails variable is not defined though'
i fail to see how you have arrived to this conclusion

Comment: You've since edited your answer which stated originally that they had not defined the `emails` variable. It is defined in the arrow function (same as if it were `export default function(emails) {...}`) There really isn't enough information in OP's post to answer this properly. For all we know, it could be a typo; perhaps it's meant to be `validateEmails(values.email)`

Comment: your comment pointed out that `emails` was defined.. i missed that in my original answer and so i edited it accordingly..
but still, if `emails` is not assigned a value it would result in the same error..
thank you..